# JPA schema validation - how to raise an informative error message on discrepancies in column definitions and keys?

Tags: validation, jpa, schema

I have a case where the table `DDL` might be changed outside of `JPA` so would like to detect it before attempting to persist any of the entities. An exception shall be raised if such discrepancy is detected and the error message shall be precise about the violation (e.g. `point to the missing column, column of the wrong type/width or a missing foreign/unique key`
).

Right now I am using `Hibernate` as a `JPA provider`. I tried to find documentation on the behavior of `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema` but there is none in the `JavaDoc`.

Can anyone give an example how to do this - either with `Hibernate` or with any of the other `JPA` providers?

Answer (score 1):

With EclipseLink you can enable the integrity checker to validate the schema.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/IntegrityChecker